# Placeholder image for multiple youtube videos

Tags: jquery, css, youtube

Through some research, I figured out a way to display my own thumbnail that targets a youtube video when it is clicked. The issue I am running into is that when another video on the page is clicked, both thumbnails start to play, instead of just the one targeted since they are sharing the same classes.   On the jQuery, I have tried to target only the .image that is being clicked by using this and using closest, parent and siblings. I may just be typing them wrong but being a beginner I am having some trouble figuring it out.

HTML

```
<div class="youtube" style="display:none;">
  <iframe width="382" height="262" src="" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img src="img/example.jpg" width="382" height="262" class="image" />
```

jQuery

```
$('.image').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.youtube').show().find("iframe").attr("src","videourl?autoplay=1");
});
```

Comment: That is because you are using class `.youtube` instead of unique IDs such as `#youtube1` `#youtube2`. The `.youtube` will affect all with that class.

Comment: I could use unique ID's, however when there are 100 videos that does not seem logical. There's got to be a better way using classes.

Comment: Give your Image an ID and you won't have to duplicate code... `$('.image').click(function() { var ID = $(this).val(); ... $('#youtube'+ID).children...`

Comment: Why not using ev.currentTarget ? You don't have to put any ID's on any element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.image').click(function() {
  startvideo = $(this).prev();
  $(this).hide();
  startvideo.show().find("iframe").attr("src","videourl?autoplay=1");
});
```

this will take previous element and before our `<img class=".image">`there is `<div class="youtube">`

 
http://jsfiddle.net/6uhyM/

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" data-videourl="http://www.youtube.com/...">

$('.image').click(function() {
      url = $(this).data("videourl")
      startvideo = $(this).prev();
      $(this).hide();
      startvideo.show().find("iframe").attr("src",url);
    });
```

Comment: This works great and seems to be the same as reikyoushin answer but with a variable startvideo keeping it a little more tight in the code. Same question still applies after this though, which is how can I change the src of each images iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this work?

```
$('.image').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  var iframe = $(this).prev().show().find("iframe");
  iframe.attr("src",iframe.data(url));
});
```

NOTE: you need the `<img class="image" />` to follow the `<div class="youtube">` immediately.. like in your example.. so multiple instances would be:

```
<div class="youtube" style="display:none;">
   <iframe width="382" height="262" src="" data-url="url-1" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img src="img/example.jpg" width="382" height="262" class="image" />

<div class="youtube" style="display:none;">
   <iframe width="382" height="262" src="" data-url="url-2" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img src="img/example.jpg" width="382" height="262" class="image" />

<div class="youtube" style="display:none;">
   <iframe width="382" height="262" src="" data-url="url-3" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img src="img/example.jpg" width="382" height="262" class="image" />
```

Comment: This one works for me, the question now is, how do I set a unique youtube URL for each image?

Comment: by using HTML5 custom data, [see here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), example has been updated to reflect the changes..

Comment: This is very smart and makes logical sense. I'm trying to troubleshoot why the video is showing blank (white) at this point, but this seems to be the most logical way to do it to me.

Comment: you can try looking at it on firebug and see what the new src value is.. so you can debug.

Comment: What your code is saying is to take whatever is in the data-url and copy that to the src of the given iFrame?

Comment: well, actually yes. what should have been on the `src=""` area you just put on `data-url=""`.. in this case the youtube URL

Comment: Ah, what it took was putting the dataurl in the img src tag as oozic suggested. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: what's the difference? its just that he put it on another tag.. does that mean its better there? i dont get it. anyway. accept what suits you. afaik i answered it before him. haha.

Comment: I think you both have identical responses, but putting the dataurl in the img tag made it work. I didn't say anyones answer was better than the other haha. Seriously though, I thank you both for your help, both of you helped me get where I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: It works if I put your data-url in the img element instead of iFrame.

Comment: that's weird. haha. anyway. its fine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep chaining on `$(this)`?

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .hide()
        .prev()
        .show()
        .find("iframe")
        .attr("src","videourl?autoplay=1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="1" ... class="image" />
<img id="2" ... class="image" />

$('.image').click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    // Now you know what Video to play etc...
});
```